# How to aggregate multiple columns into one depending on colums values?

Tags: r

I want to aggregate some columns into one using  the value.

I have a matrix like this :

```
| X  | Y1 | Y2 | Y3 | Y4 |
|----|----|----|----|----|
|id1 | 0  | 0  | 1  | 0  |
|id2 | 0  | 1  | 0  | 0  |
|id3 | 0  | 1  | 0  | 0  |
|id4 | 0  | 0  | 0  | 1  |
|id5 | 0  | 1  | 0  | 0  |
|id6 | 1  | 0  | 0  | 0  |
```

And I want to retrieve a matrix like this :

```
| X  | Y  |
|----|----|
|id1 | Y3 |
|id2 | Y2 |
|id3 | Y2 |
|id4 | Y4 |
|id5 | Y2 |
|id6 | Y1 |
```

I don't know how i can do this.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have a look at tidyr's 'gather' function, there'll be many examples on SO. https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tidyr/versions/0.8.0/topics/gather  DF %>% gather(key = X, value = Y, -X)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a vectorized method using `max.col` from base R,

```
names(df)[max.col(df[-1])+1]
#[1] "Y3" "Y2" "Y2" "Y4" "Y2" "Y1"
```

To construct your output, you can simply use `data.frame`,

```
data.frame(X = df$X, Y = names(df)[max.col(df[-1])+1])
```

which gives,

> ```
>     X  Y
> 1 id1 Y3
> 2 id2 Y2
> 3 id3 Y2
> 4 id4 Y4
> 5 id5 Y2
> 6 id6 Y1
> ```

A bit more simplified version of `max.col`, since It works with logical statements as well, can be (compliments of @Jaap)

```
names(df)[max.col(df == 1)]
```

Comment: was about to post the same :-)

Comment: @Jaap heh... I was doing something with `stack` and then `max.col` hit me )

Comment: I had a slightly different option with: `names(df)[max.col(df == 1)]`

Comment: Didn't know `max.col` exists, that is a fine solution.

Answer (score 3):

One way with `tidyr` and `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  gather(key, value, -X) %>% 
  filter(value == 1) %>% 
  arrange(X)
```

Returns:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  X     key   value
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 id1   Y3    1    
2 id2   Y2    1    
3 id3   Y2    1    
4 id4   Y4    1    
5 id5   Y2    1    
6 id6   Y1    1
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                 X = c( "id1", "id2", "id3", "id4", "id5", "id6"),
                 Y1 = c( "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1"),
                 Y2 = c("0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "0"),
                 Y3 = c("1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"),
                 Y4 = c("0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `base` R solution. I use the following `data.frame` for illustration

```
df <- data.frame(X = c("id1", "id2", "id3", "id4"),
                 Y1 = c(1, 0, 0, 0),
                 Y2 = c(0, 1, 0, 1),
                 Y3 = c(0, 0, 1, 0))
df
#    X Y1 Y2 Y3
#1 id1  1  0  0
#2 id2  0  1  0
#3 id3  0  0  1
#4 id4  0  1  0
```

In the first step, for every row I will look for the position of the column that contains the value 1.

```
col_positions <- sapply(X = 1:nrow(df), FUN = function(x) which(df[x, ] == 1))
col_positions
#[1] 2 3 4 3
```

Now you can use this vector to filter `colnames(df)` and append the result to your data.

```
df$Y <- colnames(df)[col_positions]
df
#    X Y1 Y2 Y3  Y
#1 id1  1  0  0 Y1
#2 id2  0  1  0 Y2
#3 id3  0  0  1 Y3
#4 id4  0  1  0 Y2
```

If you only want to keep columns `X` and `Y`, you can select them for example as follows

```
df[, colnames(df) %in% c("X", "Y")]
```